# Working with long strings

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide

So I need some tips on working with long strings with the arduino. I have a barcode scanner working. This barcode scanner reads a persons driver license. the result is a lengthy character string of varying length that's 300+. Using substring doesn't work when looking for a certain section of the string and indexOf results in a -1 in most spots. Is there anyway getting around this? Right now I have the data just stored in a string variable.

Thanks.

Comment: Don't use String. It's slow, inefficient, and makes swiss cheese of your memory. Use the standard C string.h library routines (already included and available in your sketch).

Comment: This doesn't really sound like a task to which an Arduino is well suited.  You can probably make it work, but it's likely not the best choice.

Answer (score 2):

Since the Arduino Uno only has a few KB, 300 bytes is a considerable amount.

My advice:

- Define a fixed char[300] array, where 300 is the max amount of characters you want to support.
- Use the C (string.h) library as Majenko already suggests.

The last thing you want is that the string will be copied somehow, using up double the amount of data, or triple. It's hard to see what's going on under water, by casting or even by implicit casting a copy can be made, so 600/900 bytes are used.

For the default library, searching should work for strings longer than 256 characters. You can even write them yourself, for example if you can make it more efficient if you know something about the characters (e.g. if you can skip some because you know some patterns exist or don't exist).

Update after your comment below.

What you can try:

- Try (if existing) an example sample for the barcode scanner to see if the hardware is ok. If not possible try to make a minimal sketch.
- Double check the wiring (although it seems easy).
- Try different wires (maybe a jumper wire is malfunctioning).
- Try another sketch using serial, but without the barcode scanner (to verify RX/TX is not broken on the Arduino).

Comment: Searching substrings, with [`strstr()`](https://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__string.html#ga6a441da9211eb85881d99c60b1003552) or [`strcasestr()`](https://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__string.html#gae240697c78aee7b9c47cb2c9452526ea) works, of course, with strings of any length. And note that, if the program is light enough, it would make sense to allocate 1 KiB to the string.

Comment: @EdgarBonet True ... I rephrased my answer slightly, thanks!

Comment: The barcode scanner is the heaviest part of this build. I have a few I2C devices, and maybe 5 digital outputs at most. The physical aspect with outputs is really light.

Comment: I updated my answer.

Comment: In response to your answer, I'm pretty sure the hardware is fine. I WISH it was serial but all I was given to work with is a USB scanner and USB shield. When scanned in and stored in the string variable, I can Serial.print the data just fine. My issue only comes when searching the string. For drivers license, there are delimiters like "dbb" to indicate date of birth. I'm essentially trying to search for the occurrence of this delimiter and extract the date of birth, turn it to a julian date, compare with an RTC module, and make sure the person is over 21.

Comment: Can you put in your question the exact code you use for searching? (including a Serial.print of the values before and after your search).

Comment: I don't have the code with me currently, but I was just using Serial.println(DL.indexOf("dbb")); and I received a -1 for the output. I'm using indexOf to get the index, add 3 to bypass the delimiter, and then I was going to get the next 8 digits for the date. When I am able to, I am going to put it into a character array and use strstr() as suggested. If I do Serial.println(DL); I get the data displayed just fine.

Comment: my answer posted

Answer (score 0):

So when printing my string variable, I get the full, uninterrupted string displayed to me. I decided to index through my string with a for loop and come to find out, I had many null characters included in the string itself. I did a check to make sure that the character isn't a NULL character before appending it to my string upon creation, and that seemed to do the trick. indexOf is working now.

Reason I decided to index through my string is because I tried to string.toCharArray(buff, DL.length()); and despite the length, I would only get one character pushed into buff.

Thanks for all the tips guys!

Comment: Functions of the “str” family, like `strstr()`, expect NUL-terminated strings, and thus they can't handle character arrays with embedded NULs. Arbitrary character arrays, however, are handled just fine with functions from the “mem” family, like [`memmem()`](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__string.html#ga1c22a39c9d936f18aa0764e331e3cddc), which is the equivalent of `strstr()` for arbitrary arrays.